# Pythonのhttp.serverでSet-CookieでセットしたはずのCookieが取得できない

Tags: python, http, cookie

Pythonのhttp.serverでSet-Cookieを送ったのですが、pathとdomainが一致したとしても、Cookieヘッダが返ってきません。
なぜなのでしょうか?

下記のコードです。

```
import datetime
import time
import os
import hashlib
import http.server
import cgi

class handle(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == "/login":
            thisyear = datetime.datetime.now().year
            ripemd160 = hashlib.new("ripemd160")
            ripemd160.update(os.urandom(800))
            session_id = ripemd160.hexdigest()
            os.environ["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "POST"
            self.send_response(303, self.responses[303][0])
            self.send_header("Content-Length", 0)
            self.send_header("Set-Cookie", "session=" + session_id + "; domain=http://127.0.0.1:8152; path=/; expires=" + time.strftime(
                "%a, %d-%b-{0:d} %H:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime()).format(thisyear + 2)) #有効期限は2年間
            self.send_header("Location", "/")
            self.end_headers()
            login_data = cgi.FieldStorage(self.rfile, self.headers)
            print(login_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain 属性を削除するか、 Domain 属性を 127.0.0.1 にすれば動くのではないかと思います。

Domain に "http://127.0.0.1:8152" が指定されていますが、Domainに指定できるのはドメインなので、http://の部分は付けません。Cookieはポート番号を考慮しないのでポート番号 :8152 も付けられません。Domain属性の指定が正しくない場合ブラウザはクッキーを無視します。
そもそも domain 属性は指定しなければ、現在のホスト以外にはクッキーは送信されないので domain 属性はデフォルトより広い範囲にクッキーを送信したいのでなければ必要ないのですが、本当に domain 属性をつける必要がありますか？

Comment: 疑問に思ったのですが、domainは127.0.0.1とlocalhostでは同じと認識されるのでしょうか?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.1.3 The domain string and the string are identical. ですから、loclhostと127.0.0.1は別物として扱われるかと思います。